# Как получить элементы в массиве назад....?

Tags: c#

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string read = Console.ReadLine();
        string[] items = { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7" };
        for (int i = 0; i <= items.Length; i++)
        {
            var re = items[i].Take(-3);
            foreach (var asd in re)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(asd);
            }
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Имею я такой код.
Вопрос таков: когда я, от руки ввел какое то число, все равно, какое, задача алгоритма показать(вывести на экран) три элемента перед моим введенным значением, как это сделать ?

```
Пример :    6  вывод: 3
```

Comment: Вы сами как то пытались решить вашу задачу?

Comment: @tym32167 да, вот щяс этим и занимаюсь! Честно, не знаю как эффективнее, но варианты решения этой задачи у меня есть...пытаюсь..:-(

Comment: так покажите что пытаетесь и что не получается

Comment: это один из методов, то есть я ввел от руки и из массива отнялись 3 элемента назад, и этот 3-ий элемент нужно отобразить...

Comment: @tym32167 или по индексу...может быть

Comment: Идите с конца массива, как встретите элемент, что ввели, то отсчитайте вторым циклом 3 элемента вперед и выводите, что там стоит

Comment: @tym32167 "отсчитайте вторым циклом 3 элемента вперед и выводите" - как это сделать ?

Comment: ну, в вашем примере вы считаете циклом вперед, от начала к концу. Но вы же можете таким же циклом считать назад - от конца к началу, для этого вам надо поменять условия в цикле

Comment: Сел писать и понял, что обратный цикл вам не нужен. Оформил вам в ответ 2 варианта

Comment: и ещё 2 варианта с выводом 3 чисел. Выбирайте :)

Answer (score 3):

Решаем с помощью LINQ

```
string read = Console.ReadLine();
string[] items = { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7" }; 
Console.WriteLine(items.Reverse().SkipWhile(x=>x!=read).Skip(3).FirstOrDefault());
```

Решаем с помощью циклов

```
string read = Console.ReadLine();
string[] items = { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7" };
for (int i = 0; i < items.Length; i++)
    if (read == items[i] && i >= 3)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(items[i - 3]);
        break;
    }
```

С помощью Array.IndexOf

```
string read = Console.ReadLine();
string[] items = { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7" };
int ind = Array.IndexOf(items, read) - 3;
if (ind >= 0) Console.WriteLine(items[ind]);
```

Вывести 3 элемента перед найденным

```
string read = Console.ReadLine();
string[] items = { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7" };
for (int i = 0; i < items.Length; i++)
    if (read == items[i] && i >= 3)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(items[i - 1]);
        Console.WriteLine(items[i - 2]);
        Console.WriteLine(items[i - 3]);
        break;
    }
```

То же самое с помощью цикла

```
string read = Console.ReadLine();
string[] items = { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7" };
for (int i = 0; i < items.Length; i++)
    if (read == items[i] && i >= 3)
    {
        for(int j=1; j<=3; j++)
            Console.WriteLine(items[i-j]);
        break;
    }
```

Comment: Можно ещё добавить вариант с Array.IndexOf

Comment: @АндрейNOP спс, добавил